# windows cannot cd to another drive even with /d switch - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, windows-10

For some reason I'm unable to change drives. I get the error `The system cannot find the path specified.`

I'm sure it was working a month ago and haven't tried it since then.

```
C:\Users\Username>cd D:\ /d
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Username>cd G:\ /d
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Within the same drive, I can change directories though.

```
C:\Users\Username>cd .virtualbox

C:\Users\Username\.VirtualBox>

C:\Users\Username\.VirtualBox>cd C:\

C:\>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /?
Displays the name of or changes the current directory.

CHDIR [/D] [drive:][path]
CHDIR [..]
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
CD [..]
```

The syntax is incorrect.  It should be:

cd /d D:

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `cd` command to change drives. CD stands for "Change Directory" not "Change Drive". To change drives simply enter the drive letter followed by a colon. At the prompt enter `D:` and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it with no backslash.**

Proper: `X:` and `enter`.

No longer working: `CD X:\`

I do not recall in what version of windows they did this, but it happened at a point.

So to change the actual disk, writing it as `X:` is sufficient, no `CD` command needed.

You later use `CD` to navigate desired directories in the current drive.